# lsblk and df -H don't match

Tags: 16.04, mount, disk-usage

Office machine - After running `lsblk` I noticed I am not using all the disk space that is one the machine,

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0  63.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdb1   8:17   0 401.9G  0 part /
loop6    7:6    0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
loop4    7:4    0 101.9M  1 loop /snap/skype/23
loop2    7:2    0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4571
loop0    7:0    0   137M  1 loop /snap/skype/33
sda      8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk 
loop5    7:5    0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4650
loop3    7:3    0 146.2M  1 loop /snap/skype/30
```

And when I call `df -H`,

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             34G     0   34G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.8G  652M  6.1G  10% /run
/dev/sdb1       425G   76G  328G  19% /
tmpfs            34G   39M   34G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            34G     0   34G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop4      107M  107M     0 100% /snap/skype/23
tmpfs           6.8G  173k  6.8G   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/loop6       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/4486
/dev/loop3      154M  154M     0 100% /snap/skype/30
/dev/loop2       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/4571
/dev/loop5       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/4650
/dev/loop0      144M  144M     0 100% /snap/skype/33
```

I wonder why the `sda      8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk` is not showing up here. How can I safely add (mount) or use this space? And why it is not showing up in `df -H`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `sda      8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk` doesn't have a mountpoint. `df` handles only mounted filesystems. So if it's unmounted it won't show up.  For that same reason, the `/dev/sdb2` doesn't show up also.

Also  /dev/sda seems to have no partition table there. If you think it should, check the disk health. Otherwise, if it doesn't have a partition table, create one. Mounting can be done via file manager or `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1` for partition `sda1` for example

Comment: Thanks - How can I create  partition table without risking everything else on the disk?

Comment: Does it have data stored there ? Backup the data first, then use `gparted` program for creating partition table.

Answer (score 5):

- **`lsblk`** lists all mass storage devices and partitions on them, including mounted file systems, unmounted file systems and devices without any file system.
- **`df`** 'reports file system disk space usage', which means that it lists mounted file systems and also file systems in RAM.

  - Please notice the difference between

    ```
    df -H   # print sizes in powers of 1000 (e.g., 1.1G)
    ```

    and

    ```
    df -h   # print sizes in powers of 1024 (e.g., 1023M)
    ```

    `lsblk` lists sizes in powers of 1024, so it matches `df -h` best.

---

It seems that there is no file system on `/dev/sda` as already described by @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy.