# Discrepancy between lsblk, df and Disks

Tags: partitioning

I don't understand the differences in size produced by the following commands:

```
$ lsblk
...
nvme0n1               259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1           259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2           259:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3           259:3    0 237.3G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt   253:0    0 237.3G  0 crypt 
    └─ubuntu--vg-root 253:1    0 237.3G  0 lvm   /


$ df -h
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  233G  203G   19G  92% /
```

Moreover, the Disks utility displays yet another number:
[Disks screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ovPm.png)

Where do 237.3G, 233G and 255 GB from Disks come from and why do they differ?

I also tried:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 62194688 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lsblk and df -H don't match](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039115/lsblk-and-df-h-dont-match)

Comment: From the Linux Manual page and you can do the same for the other commands to learn about them. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems Disks show result in Gigabytes, while the CLI utilities output in GibiBytes. [A conversion utility is here](https://www.gbmb.org/gb-to-gib). 255 GB = 237 GiB.

Also, `df` only shows usable space, while `lsblk` shows block devices. Therefore, it seems 4 GiB on the disk is reserved for root.

To see how many blocks are reserved, run this command:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root | grep "lock count"
```

Then divide `Reserved block count` with `Block count`, and you get the percentage that is reserved, which can easily be converted to GiB of storage.